# Statistics: Why are school grades qualitative variable?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am struggling to understand, why in descriptive statistics we say that school grades are a qualitative and not quantitative variable? I can understand why color of the hair is qualitative, but grades are numerical...

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you live. For example, in Greece grades are in a scale 1-20, therefore quantitative.But in the U.S. for example they have A,B,C.. so you could say that there the grades is a qualitative variable.

Comment: Our professor says that though grades are numerical (1-5), we consider them qualitative (it is in Germany). But why would it be?

Comment: It could be that there are certain fixed possible grades, only the integers from $1$ to $5$ and therefore by some abuse of definitions grades are considered quantitative. My knowledge in statistics isn't really that great to be able to say more...

Comment: "Numbers" (1, 2, 3,  4, 5 or 1-20) can be labels for the levels of a categorical variable, which does not make them numerical. //  In a math course where course grades are mainly derived from test scores, they might be _nearly_ numerical; in a pottery course where your A means the teacher liked your vase better than mine which got a B, probably not numerical at all. // If truly numerical, A=4 and C=2 should clearly represent the same degree of _something_ as B=3 and B=3. // You can do arithmetic on numerical obs. (e.g., to get a sample mean). With _ordinal_ categorical you can get median.

Comment: @ArtemSmirnov : Does a grade of "2" mean twice as much of something as does a grade of "1"?

Answer (score 1):

A finer categorization of the "level of data" is surely *"nominal scaled"*, *"ordinal scaled"*, *"interval scaled"* and *"ratio scaled"* (see more about this in wikipedia).

*"nominal"* are data for instance from your example of *color of hair*, or telephone numbers or ICD-codes or many labelings ...
*"interval"*  are data like temperature, for instance degree of Celsius or of Fahrenheit, which we give numerical values on the scale of real numbers, and "*ratio*" if they have a zero which are inherent/relevant with the meaning of the measure, such that relations as "double" or "half" make sense.

With grades in school it is between those concepts; while they are usually no measure related to the natural or real numbers, they still have an *order*: level "A" is better than "B" and that is better than "C" or so -and what is precisely what we want usually with such grades-, but what *"nominal*" data don't have. So the term *"ordinal scale"* has been introduced.

There is a lot more to say about, but I think wikipedia is a good-enough source for the beginning.